# Change function to Signal login

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to run this function only when the user logs in.

```
def purchased_today(self):
        check = Rating.objects.filter(user=self.user, book__collection=self.collection, score__lte=4).order_by('newest')[:50]
        a = check.count()
        today = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        if self.last_checked.date().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") != today:
            return a
```

I tried it:

```
    @receiver(user_logged_in)
    def purchased_today(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
        check = Rating.objects.filter(user=self.user, book__collection=self.collection, score__lte=4).order_by('newest')[:50]
        a = check.count()
        today = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        if self.last_checked.date().strftime("%Y-%m-%d") != today:
            return a
```

But it returns:

```
name 'self' is not defined.
```

how can i replace the self?

Comment: I do not see the correlation between your two methods. In your first method, self is your argument. Try to check to which argument self is supposed to refer to in the second method ?

Comment: In which class is the first `purchased_today` defined? It's a method, not just a function, since it takes `self`. And how is the first method called? We have no idea what `self` is, so there's no way we can help right now.

Comment: @BlueSheepToken, sorry, Im begginer in Django. The first method run correctly, but It run continuously. I need that this method only run once when the user login. I tried the Signals, but not run.

Comment: @dirkgroten, ```purchased_today``` in the models.py.

Comment: But which class???? And how is it called?

Comment: Also returning something doesn't make sense, since django doesn't do anything with the return value of a signal handler. It's not clear what your function is doing, what should happen when the user logs in and what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what kind of class self is referring to. But in this case, I would write code outside of that class that triggers on user_log_in, and instantiates a user class when that happens. Once the class is instantiated, you can call

```
purchased_today(self)
```

as before.
If you want to separate out the functions that can be run anytime versus the ones that must only be run when user is logged in, then I would make 2 separate classes and trigger instantiation of the 2nd one when user_log_in triggers.

The control code for the callback should be outside of the class either way.